# download result mp3 file after processing in wavesurfer.js and Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I made extensive 2 days research on the topic, but there is no really well explained piece that would work.

So the flow is following:

1. load `mp3` (store bought) `cbr 320` into `wavesurfer`
2. apply all the changes you need
3. download processed result back to `mp3` file (without usage of server)

Ive seen online apps that can do that, nothing is transmitted to server, all happens in the browser.

when we inspect `wavesurfer`, we have access to these:

[image: wavesurfer backend references]

The goal would be to use already available references from `wavesurfer` to produce the download `mp3`.

from my understanding this can be done with `MediaRecorder`, `WebCodecs API` or some libraries like `lamejs`.

Ive tried to find working example of how to do it with two first methods but without luck. I also tried to do it with `lamejs` using their example provided on the git but i am getting errors from the lib that are hard to debug, most likely related to providing wrong input.

So far i only managed to download `wav` file using following script:

```
handleCopyRegion = (region, instance) => {
    var segmentDuration = region.end - region.start;

    var originalBuffer = instance.backend.buffer;
    var emptySegment = instance.backend.ac.createBuffer(
        originalBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        Math.ceil(segmentDuration * originalBuffer.sampleRate),
        originalBuffer.sampleRate
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < originalBuffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
        var chanData = originalBuffer.getChannelData(i);
        var emptySegmentData = emptySegment.getChannelData(i);
        var mid_data = chanData.subarray(
            Math.ceil(region.start * originalBuffer.sampleRate),
            Math.ceil(region.end * originalBuffer.sampleRate)
        );
        emptySegmentData.set(mid_data);
    }

    return emptySegment;
};

bufferToWave = (abuffer, offset, len) => {
    var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
            length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
            buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
            view = new DataView(buffer),
            channels = [],
            i,
            sample,
            pos = 0;

    // write WAVE header
    setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
    setUint32(length - 8); // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"

    setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16); // length = 16
    setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
    setUint16(16); // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

    setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(length - pos - 4); // chunk length

    // write interleaved data
    for (i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
        channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

    while (pos < length) {
        for (i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {
            // interleave channels
            sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
            sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767) | 0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
            view.setInt16(pos, sample, true); // update data chunk
            pos += 2;
        }
        offset++; // next source sample
    }

    // create Blob
    return new Blob([buffer], { type: "audio/wav" });

    function setUint16(data) {
        view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
        pos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
        view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
        pos += 4;
    }
};

const cutSelection = this.handleCopyRegion(
    this.wavesurfer.regions.list.cut,
    this.wavesurfer
);
const blob = this.bufferToWave(cutSelection, 0, cutSelection.length);
// you can now download wav from the blob
```

Is there a way to avoid making `wav` and right away make `mp3` and download it, or if not make `mp3` from that `wav`, if so how it can be done?

I mainly tried to use `wavesurfer.backend.buffer` as input, because this reference is `AudioBuffer` and accessing `.getChannelData(0|1)` gives you `left` and `right` channels. But didnt accomplish anything, maybe i am thinking wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is the steps we need to do:

1. Get `buffer` data from the wavesurfer player
2. Analyze the `buffer` to get the number of Channels(STEREO or MONO), channels data and Sample rate.
3. Use `lamejs` library to convert buffer to the MP3 `blob` file
4. Then we can get that download link from blob

### Here is a quick [DEMO](https://codepen.io/mostafa-es/pen/oNWjdxL)

and also the JS code:

```
function downloadMp3() {
  var MP3Blob = analyzeAudioBuffer(wavesurfer.backend.buffer);
  console.log('here is your mp3 url:');
  console.log(URL.createObjectURL(MP3Blob));
}

function analyzeAudioBuffer(aBuffer) {
    let numOfChan = aBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        btwLength = aBuffer.length * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
        btwArrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(btwLength),
        btwView = new DataView(btwArrBuff),
        btwChnls = [],
        btwIndex,
        btwSample,
        btwOffset = 0,
        btwPos = 0;
    setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
    setUint32(btwLength - 8); // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"
    setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16); // length = 16
    setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
    setUint16(16); // 16-bit
    setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(btwLength - btwPos - 4); // chunk length

    for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < aBuffer.numberOfChannels; btwIndex++)
        btwChnls.push(aBuffer.getChannelData(btwIndex));

    while (btwPos < btwLength) {
        for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < numOfChan; btwIndex++) {
            // interleave btwChnls
            btwSample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, btwChnls[btwIndex][btwOffset])); // clamp
            btwSample = (0.5 + btwSample < 0 ? btwSample * 32768 : btwSample * 32767) | 0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
            btwView.setInt16(btwPos, btwSample, true); // write 16-bit sample
            btwPos += 2;
        }
        btwOffset++; // next source sample
    }

    let wavHdr = lamejs.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(btwArrBuff));

    //Stereo
    let data = new Int16Array(btwArrBuff, wavHdr.dataOffset, wavHdr.dataLen / 2);
    let leftData = [];
    let rightData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
                 leftData.push(data[i]);
                 rightData.push(data[i + 1]);
    }
    var left = new Int16Array(leftData);
    var right = new Int16Array(rightData);



    //STEREO
    if (wavHdr.channels===2)
        return bufferToMp3(wavHdr.channels, wavHdr.sampleRate,  left,right);
    //MONO
    else if (wavHdr.channels===1)
        return bufferToMp3(wavHdr.channels, wavHdr.sampleRate,  data);
    

    function setUint16(data) {
        btwView.setUint16(btwPos, data, true);
        btwPos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
        btwView.setUint32(btwPos, data, true);
        btwPos += 4;
    }
  }

  function bufferToMp3(channels, sampleRate, left, right = null) {
    var buffer = [];
    var mp3enc = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(channels, sampleRate, 128);
    var remaining = left.length;
    var samplesPerFrame = 1152;
  
  
    for (var i = 0; remaining >= samplesPerFrame; i += samplesPerFrame) {
  
        if (!right)
        {
            var mono = left.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
            var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(mono);
        }
        else {
            var leftChunk = left.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
            var rightChunk = right.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
            var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(leftChunk,rightChunk);
        }
            if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
                    buffer.push(mp3buf);//new Int8Array(mp3buf));
            }
            remaining -= samplesPerFrame;
    }
    var d = mp3enc.flush();
    if(d.length > 0){
            buffer.push(new Int8Array(d));
    }
  
    var mp3Blob = new Blob(buffer, {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
    //var bUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3Blob);
  
    // send the download link to the console
    //console.log('mp3 download:', bUrl);
    return mp3Blob;
  
  }
```

Let me know if you have any question about the code